# Why is there no Volatile.Read(ref T location) where T : struct?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

There is a [Volatile.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.threading.volatile) method for all primitives and reference types, why is there no [Volatile.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.threading.volatile) for structures? Same applies to [Volatile.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.threading.volatile). Likewise the old [Thread.VolatileRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread(v=vs.110).aspx) methods didn't have one for structs either.

What is the reason behind this? I can declare volatile structs in a class, why can't I do volatile reads with these methods?

Comment: I guess that's because struct can have arbitrary size in memory, so you cannot (in general) read it atomically.

Comment: The C# language creates the illusion that you can read or write a struct with a single operation.  But that is just an illusion, the processor can only access fields.  The Volatile type is quite dangerous if you don't understand it correctly, the threading race bugs you'll get if you don't use it correctly are utterly impossible to debug.  You might want a full MemoryBarrier() but high odds you should not overlook the `lock` keyword here.  We can't tell of course, you did not show what you intended.  Not using SO correctly is also a big mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only a guarantee in volatile operations if they're also atomic, which is not the case for all but the simplest structs (e.g. one field of a primitive or reference type, or any struct that fits 64 bits/8 bytes).

For instance, what would you expect from such `Volatile` methods on a 768 bits/96 bytes struct?  Anything bigger than the greatest supported atomic operation would actually result in multiple volatile writes, each of which would be immediately visible without any guarantee.

In Microsoft implementations of .NET, long and double `Volatile` methods are atomic.  Even on 32-bit architectures, at the cost of using interlocked operations in such architectures.

Comment: I wonder, will Volatile.Read with double or long also be atomic on 32 bit architecture?

Comment: In MS implementations, long and double `Volatile` methods are atomic, even on 32-bit archs at the cost of using interlocked operations in such archs.